# "To know somebody" as in "have knowledge of"

Tags: difference, verb

In English, "to know somebody" may have two different meanings:

> Do you know my neighbor Felix? (acquainted with)
>
> Do you know Angela Merkel? (have knowledge of)

The first meaning is translated as "kennen".

> Kennst du meinen Nachbarn Felix?

For the second meaning, it seems that the closest [translation](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=know&l=deen&in=&lf=de) is "to recognize": erkennen

> Erkennst du Angela Merkel?

Is this correct? Also, if I say

> Kennst du Angela Merkel?

does it give the wrong meaning?

Comment: The closest translation–according to the dictionary–is "wissen" or "kennen". You ask for "have knowledge of" and Pons suggest "know (have information/knowledge): wissen, kennen". If you scroll down to the "recognize"-part and look at the examples, you'd see that they have nothing in common with your examples here. That is, "erkennen" is clearly wrong here. It's still valid for a different context. "Do you recognize her on this picture?" -> "Erkennst du sie auf diesem Bild?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes,

> Kennst Du Angela Merkel?

is ambiguous, but so is the english version.

> Erkennst du Angela Merkel?

depends on something that can be seen (or heard, felt...) at the moment.

To remove the ambiguity, use

> Weißt Du wer Angela Merkel ist?

Comment: I would understand "Erkennst du Angela Merkel?" as in: Do you **recognize** her.

Comment: Yes, and the original poster mentioned it as a translation of "recognize". I tried to point out the difference to "kennst du".

Comment: Note that "Kennst du X?" is used despite its ambiguity. "Kennst du schon das neue Spiel X?" For a more general inquiry you can also use "Hast du schon (mal) von/über X gehört/gelesen?" but that's farther away.

Comment: Another possibility du distinguish is `persönlich kennen`: "Kennst du Angela Merkel persönlich?". This is only used for acquantainces.

Comment: Weißt means to "know about." Everyone "knows about" Angela Merkel, only a few people actually KNOW her.

Answer (score 0):

You are spot on.

*Erkennen* means *to recognize*, thus "Erkennst Du..." always means "Do you recognize".

*Kennen* means *knowing / to know* in the sense of being acquainted with (in terms of people) and *to know* in the sense of being familiar with situations/locations etc.

"Kennst du Angela Merkel?" clearly means "Do you now A.M." – and has no other meaning and will never be mistaken for anything else.